# Access JSON sub levels by name

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following example JSON

```
var data = {
  "menu": [
    {
      "name": "Event A",
      "sub": [{
          "name": "Sub Event A 1",
          "sub": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Sub Event A 2",
          "sub": [{
              "name": "Sub Sub Event A 2",
              "sub": null
            }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Event B",
      "sub": [{
          "name": "Sub Event B 1",
          "sub": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Sub Event B 2",
          "sub": [{
              "name": "Sub Sub Event B 2",
              "sub": null
            }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I'm creating a menu I can easily choose whether to use `Event A` or `Event B` as the source as follows:

```
$(data.menu[0].sub).each(function(){ /* menu[0] therefore first, Event A */
    $menu1.append(
      getMenuItem1(this)
    );
});
```

**Question**

Is it possible to select this by the value of the `name` field?

Something like: `$(data.menu[name="Event A"].sub)`

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object initializer. JSON is a textual notation for data exchange. If you're working with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to select this by the value of the `name` field?

Yes, using either `Array#find` (if you just want the first one) or `Array#filter` (if you want all matching ones).

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (ES2015+, but can be shimmed):

```
var firstMatchingItem = data.menu.find(function(entry) {
    return entry.name == "Event A";
});
```

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (ES5+, but can be shimmed):

```
var matchingItems = data.menu.filter(function(entry) {
    return entry.name == "Event A";
});
```

---

They both look simpler with ES2015's arrow functions:

```
var firstMatchingItem = data.menu.find(entry => entry.name == "Event A");

var matchingItems = data.menu.filter(entry => entry.name == "Event A");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate and find the menu you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.menu.length; i++) {
    if (data.menu[i].name == "Event A") {
        var menu = data.menu[i];
        //do stuff!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or similar for this. Its very easy to use. Using [lodash filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
_.filter(data, { name: "Event A" });
```

In your case:

```
$(_.filter(data, { name: "Event A" })[0].sub)
```